# Div being stretched on any mobile safari

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-safari

I have a slideshow with divs which are the selectors for the images. All they are, are just divs with a border. This is what it looks like on every single browser apart from mobile safari

[image]

And this is mobile Safari

[image]

Here is the css for them:

```
.slick-dots {
  padding-left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
.slick-dots li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 3px;
}
.slick-dots li button {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  opacity: 1;
  color: transparent;
}
.slick-dots li.slick-active button {
  background: #000;
}

.inspiration .slick-dots,
.destinations .slick-dots {
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.inspiration .slick-dots li button,
.destinations .slick-dots li button {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.inspiration .slick-dots li.slick-active button,
.destinations .slick-dots li.slick-active button {
  background: #fff;
}

.slick-slide img {
  display: inline !important;
}
```

Its a set height and width in pixels of 18px. It looks like if i change the width below 18px it doesn't go any less wide... Has any one seen anything like this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove your width and height and set css like this

> padding:9px;

this may be fix the safari problem

Comment: Thanks for the help Tommy!